# Unable to resolve service for type while attempting to activate while using EF Core 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Here is my `Context` class:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context(DbContextOptions<Context> options) : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<Widget> Widget { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the `IWidgetRepository`:

```
public interface IWidgetRepository
{
    List<Widget> GetWidgets();
}
```

and the `WidgetRepository`:

```
public class WidgetRepository:IWidgetRepository
{
    private readonly Context context;

    public WidgetRepository(Context dbContext)
    {
        context = dbContext;
    }

    public List<Widget> GetWidgets()
    {
        return context.Widget.ToList();
    }
}
```

Here is the startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("Context");

    services.AddDbContext<Context>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

    services.AddControllersWithViews();
}
```

Here is the config:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "Context": "Data Source=10.224.78.219\\sql2014;Initial Catalog=BackOffice;User Id=sa;Password=Pwhois110"
  },
```

And the controller:

```
private readonly IWidgetRepository widgetRepo;

public HomeController(IWidgetRepository widget)
{
    widgetRepo = widget;
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
    var x = widgetRepo.GetWidgets();
    return View();
}
```

I am getting this error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'BackOffice.Repository.IWidgetRepository' while attempting to activate 'BackOffice.UI.Controllers.HomeController'.

Why is this for?

Comment: Did you register your IWidgetRepository provider in ConfigureServices()?

Comment: I don't know "why is this for" (most likely missing service registration), but the error has nothing to do with EF Core - read the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined the `IWidgetRepository` and its implementation just fine - and the `HomeController` uses that interface as a dependency - but you've never set up a declaration for .NET Core as to **how** to resolve that interface to a concrete class.

Add this in your startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("Context");

    services.AddDbContext<Context>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

    services.AddControllersWithViews();

    // add an entry for your interface + implementation
    services.AddTransient<IWidgetRepository, WidgetRepository>();
}
```

You can use `.AddTransient()`, `.AddScoped()` or `.AddSingleton()` to define the lifetime of your class that implements this interface. Read more [about service lifetimes in .NET Core here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#service-lifetimes)

Read **a lot more** about [dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0) in the official MS docs.